# Linux/Windows hosts file

Tags: linux, redirection, hosts-file

I need redirect the domain (*www.pokus.cz*) to my local IP address (*192.168.1.100/preview*) because I need to make a test of my new web pages. I read that it's possible with add lines in /etc/hosts/
When I add this:

> 192.168.1.100   www.pokus.cz

it works but it's not what I need.

I need something like this

> 192.168.1.100/preview   www.pokus.cz

unfortunately this doesn't work...
Can you help me please?

Comment: to my knowledge, the hosts file does 1 thing. routes names to IP addresses. any additional routing after that would need to take place in your http server.

Comment: You need to use a web server, gateway, or proxy to edit the URL to add '/preview' to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this in the webserver configuration. In apache it's set in the vhost configuration. It depends on your server setup how this is configured. The hosts file you're referring to is meant to link a domain name to an IP-address. That domain name may not exist outside your network, or may have a different IP-address outside your network.

Comment: Thank you very much, I set up my virtual host and local hosts file and it works!